# Outgoing network bandwidth is high even for empty response

Tags: performance, nginx, logging, server, network-programming

I have a simple nginx server that monitors the requests and store them in the access logs. The requests contain data in query parameters and are about 500 bytes. My output is just a HTTP 204 response. But, when I monitor the network bandwidth, I am seeing the incoming rate as 8.44 Mbit/s and outgoing rate as 5.19 MBit/s.

Question is, why is the outgoing rate high?

The output from "tcpflow -p -C -i eth0 port 80" is below.

```
GET ############## HTTP/1.1
Host: ##############
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Forwarded: for="[############]"
Origin: ###########
Referer: #########
Save-Data: on
Scheme: http
Via: 1.1 Chrome-Compression-Proxy
X-Forwarded-For: #################
Connection: Keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; SM-J710FN Build/MMB29K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Mobile Safari/537.36


write error to stdout

HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
Date: Fri, 10 Mar 2017 04:54:43 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Type: text/plain
```

Comment: Might be more appropriate on serverfault.com

Comment: @DanField Good point.